# Relation R onto A - Am I reading this correctly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, gcd-and-lcm

I'm trying to solve an exercise which defines:

The set A = {2,3,4,5,6}

The Relation R on A where R = {(a,b)| gcd(a,b)= 1 ∧ a ≠ b}

The objective of the task is to determine the set R.

I believe I do this by finding the each occurence in the AxA subset where the gcd of each entry equals 1 and at the same time where a and b *not equal*

Am I on the right path so far - and if so - what would be the most efficient way to determine R from here on?

Comment: Yes; a pair $(a,b)$ is $R$-related iff $a$ and $b$ are different and they are relative prime. Thus, $(2,3) \in R$ while $(2,4) \notin R$.

Comment: I think you have the right idea,  The relation is reflexive, so you have 10 pairs to check.  But, if you want to be most efficient, start with the prime numbers.

Comment: @DougM I think you mean to say that the relation is irreflexive, not reflexive.